# Multiple AG groups complicated set up question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

Suppose I have two AGs:

- AG #1

  - Server A (primary)
  - Server B (replica)
- AG #2

  - Server C (primary)
  - Server D (replica)

Now I need Server F to have all the DBs from server A and C. Is it actually possible to have Server F serve as a replica in both AG #1 and AG #2?

Is this as simple as adding both the listeners (from AG #1 and AG #2) on server F?

Currently, servers on AG#1 and AG #2 are in two different WSFCs. Also, I need to add all the listeners from diff AGs to server F? In other words, server F can be the replicas server of 4 different set of AGs that is made of 8 other servers(2 node per set)?

Is there a limit to how many AG groups can be in server F for 2012 Enterprise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing additional is required. You would just add server F as another replica for both AG #1 and AG #2 (provided that you do not have collisions in your database names).

Just remember that they all need to be members of the same WSFC (given the version you are working with).

With 2012 you must have the Windows machines on the same WSFC in order to add them to an AG, as such you will not be able to use the F server for both AGs (you'll have to choose one or the other).

Comment: Thanks Nic. Which version allows the set up that I mentioned above without the machines being on the the same WSFC to be part of the AG? Thanks!

Comment: You would need to be running Windows 2016 to do domainless clusters.